# How would a Google Apps Script app that makes Oauth2 requests between 2 APIs be if it was a NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, google-apps-script

My Google Apps Script receives a webhook and makes API calls from a service it authorized with Oauth2 through a redirect URI. It then parses the data in JSON and sends it to a different API.
I need to rebuild and host something that does this written NodeJS. I don't know what this would be called or where to host it.

I tried hosting [this NodeJS app](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-WebhookNotifications-nodejs) on Heroku at an HTTPS address that should have been a sufficient redirect URI but Google will not allow me to open the page to connect the app to the API service I need to connect to. The screen warns the app might be malicious.

> I need to rewrite a Google Apps Script in NodeJS that is authorized to receive webhooks and make API requests.
>   The app needs an HTTPS address for the redirect URI
>   I don't need you to build it for me, I need to know what this is called and how and where to host it.
>   I will need to enter info for Oauth2 but I will be the only one using the app.

I see browser Oauth2 is not allowed anymore. So, from searching around it's not clear how to host the app and get it authorized in the Quickbooks API, for example, which requires Oauth2 to use.

Comment: Look into [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/).

Comment: I know the Google products above free tier would be better, but essentially I would like to build and host something to do what a Google Apps Script does. An app that does Oauth2 to authorize APIs to access it and receive webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by?

> Browser OAuth2 is not allowed

You can still make OAuth2 authentication through web client, take a look at [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) describing how to do API calls using OAuth2 flow.

Also for your specific problem you don't need to migrate to NodeJS. You can [`run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) scripts using the [`Apps Scripts API`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)

Take a look at the [NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/nodejs) if you are interesting in running your scripts from your NodeJS application.

Comment: "What do you mean by 'Browser OAuth2 is not allowed'?" Most of the time Chrome and Firefox won't let me open the Oauth page.

Comment: "Take a look at the NodeJS Quickstart if you are interesting in running your scripts from your NodeJS application. " I'm having issues with GAS spotty service. Or maybe my scripts are 'flagged for review' or something. My question is a general question 'What do I build that does what a GAS does and where do you host it?'

Comment: You can do all your functions in apps Script through the corresponding API, in your case NodeJS. The thing is that you will need to manage your scopes and OAuth flow yourself, and also Apps Script has useful functions that you will have to implement yourself.